# How to access website hosted on apache server on Amazon Windows machine from a local machine

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, wamp

A website is hosted on apache server on **Amazon EC2 Windows instance**. I want to access it from local machine.  Though if this is hosted on Linux instance, it is accessible from Other machines, but not in case of Windows Instance.

I am using wamp server and have put the server online with the below changes in **httpd.conf** :

```
Listen *:80

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    #Deny from all
</Directory>
```

When I tried to access the url from other machine, it returns : 
**Connection refused**

What configuration changes should I make to make it accessible from other machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon EC2 provides security groups which your instance is a part of, then this allows you to grant permissions to other groups of hosts on your account or other external hosts.

**A security group acts as a firewall that controls the traffic allowed to reach one or more instances.**

In Amazon EC2, security group rules are always permissive, so you cannot create any rules that deny access to a port. Also, if there is more than one rule for a specific port, the most permissive rule is always applied. So we just need to check whether port 80 is open or not, if it is not then open it.

For more reference, refer this link :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Answer (score 0):

Check : Security Group / [the name of the group your instance if set] / inbound, and see if port 80 is allowed.